# How do I use a logo that contains the company name on a website and still make use of <h1> tags?

Tags: html, css

I will be creating a fixed navigation for my website and in their will be a logo that contains the company name along with some icon. Since the company name is in the logo itself it seems pointless to use an header tag in my HTML. But I want search engines to see my company name in my h1 tag for seo purposes. Would using the css property value display:none; on the h1 element be a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this construction:

```
<h1>
  <img src="logo.png" alt="My company name">
</h1>
```

Alt text acts as the content of the h1.

Comment: feel this solution is simpler and feels less like a hack, thanks

Answer (score 1):

[alt](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_alt.asp) attribute of `img` is exactly for that: describing content of image to bots, screen readers etc.

Google [explicitly says](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2007/12/using-alt-attributes-smartly.html) that they are using it when parsing websites:

> As the Googlebot does not see the images directly, we generally
>   concentrate on the information provided in the "alt" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to have the image as a `background-image` of `h1`. You can still add text but you can style it with `font-size: 0` or use a negative `text-indent` to hide your text.